# How to make page sections full-size?

Tags: html, css

Good afternoon!

I have to stretch each section of the landing page to a full-page size.
Is it possible in my case using CSS rules only?

The section looks like this:

[image]

The css rule for this section:

```
element.style {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: can you show the HTML in fiddle ?

Comment: add `html,body{height: 100%;}`

Comment: Try this one  `html,body{width:100%; height:auto;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `100vh` which will set the height to the height of the viewport.

```css
/* for demo only ... */

body {
  margin: 0;
}
div:nth-child(1) {
    background: red;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
    background: green;
}
div:nth-child(3) {
    background: blue;
}

/* Important bit... */

div {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since its positioned absolute, you can use the following css to make it 100%.

```
element.style {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

See this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v6Lkkq4n/

Comment: Seems that it doens't work in my case: https://monosnap.com/file/0HI89uItXvwJyEt4wMLoPh1Cwu9esV

Comment: Oh, I see the parent DIV contains position:relative and has a fixed height.

This means the absolution positioned DIV cannot grow more the its relative positioned parent.

By making the DIV position:fixed, it will get out of the parent's relative position. But it will overlap everything of your website.

* Parent div is <section id="home"....../>